# Find group of repeated rows in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have an excel work sheet like

```
OrderId ----ItemName-----QTY
-------------------------------
100 -----   Note -----  10
100 -----   Pen -----   10
100 -----   Pencil -----5
101 -----   Note -----  20
101 -----   Pen -----   20
102 -----   Pen -----   30
102 -----   Pencil -----10
103 -----   Note -----  20
103 -----   Pen -----   10
103 -----   Pencil -----10
104 -----   Note -----  20
104 -----   Pen -----   10
```

Want to remove the set of duplicates on the above records. (100 & 103), (101 & 104)  are having same items
EXPECTED results should be

```
OrderId ----ItemName
-------------------
100 -----   Note
100 -----   Pen
100 -----   Pencil
101 -----   Note
101 -----   Pen
102 -----   Pen
102 -----   Pencil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Remove Duplicates` button on the `Data` tab of the ribbon.

Uncheck the first column of data in the dialog box and press OK. Duplicates will be removed in-place.

[image]